# How to clear the first cell in a row of numbers, if that first cell is 0 - with Microsoft Excel or Stata

Tags: excel, format, stata

I have the historical returns of 3000+ mutual funds.

A lot of these funds have their return history beginning with 0; however, not all of them do.

If the sequence of historical returns begins with 0, that 0 needs to deleted/replaced with a blank space.

My data looks something like this

1),,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,5,2,7,43,7,9,23,7,9

2),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6,3,21,5,3,2,6,2,4

3),,,,,,,0,9,2,4,7,2,4,56,7,3,5,4,1

4),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,2,8,9,3,4,6,1,3,3

5),,,,,,,,,,,7,0,4,2,4,6,7,4,2,5,7,7

The commas separate different cells. So for rows 1),3) & 4), I'd need to delete the 0 that begins the sequence of returns. 2) and 6) need to remain untouched.

How can I do this? I'd rather a solution in Excel, but I can use Stata if needed.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to create a formula that deletes the contents of a cell, if its value is '0.00' and the 2 cells to the left are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two ways to do this in Stata.

```
clear
input byte(v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15 v16 v17 v18 v19 v20 v21 v22 v23 v24 v25 v26 v27 v28)
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . 0 5 2 7 43 7 9 23 7 9 . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6 3 21 5 3 2 6 2 4 
. . . . . . . 0 9 2 4 7 2 4 56 7 3 5 4 1 . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 0 2 8 9 3 4 6 1 3 3 . 
. . . . . . . . . . . 7 0 4 2 4 6 7 4 2 5 7 7 . . . . . 
end
tempfile f
save "`f'"

list v1-v21, noobs compress

* The looping method
gen nomis = 0
qui foreach v of varlist v* {
    replace nomis = nomis + 1 if !mi(`v')
    replace `v' = . if `v' == 0 & nomis == 1
    count if nomis == 0
    if r(N) == 0 continue, break
}
list v1-v21, noobs compress

* this is easier to do with data in long form
use "`f'", clear
gen id = _n
reshape long v, i(id) j(n)
bysort id (n): gen nomis = sum(!mi(v)) // this is a running sum!
replace v = . if v == 0 & nomis == 1
drop nomis
reshape wide v, i(id) j(n)
list v1-v21, noobs compress
```